# Simple Validation API Issue Java Swing

Tags: validation, java-6, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans 6.8 , JDK 1.6 and downloaded Simple Validation API. When I try the code, it gives me errors referencing "org/openide" classes.

Could this be a compatibility issue? How can I resolve this?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openide/util/Lookup
        at org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingComponentDecorationFactory.getDefault(SwingComponentDecorationFactory.java:154)
        at org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.<init>(SwingValidationGroup.java:82)
        at org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.create(SwingValidationGroup.java:87)
```

Comment: Having the same issue here.

Comment: Having the same issue here (2x)

Comment: This is a duplicate question. It was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299470/netbeans-6-8-jdk-1-6-and-simple-validation-api